# Packer : how to avoid providing ssh_private_key_file in CI/CD pipeline?

Tags: packer

I m running locally packer with ansible and terraform and it works fine.

Now i want to include these in my github actions ci/cd pipeline.

The packer hcl file is like this :

```
variable "do_token" {
  type    = string
  default = env("DO_PAT")
}
variable "pvt_key" {
  type    = string
  default = env("SSH_PVT_KEY")
}
packer {
  required_plugins {
    digitalocean = {
      version = ">= 1.0.0"
      source  = "github.com/hashicorp/digitalocean"
    }
  }
}

source "digitalocean" "example" {
  api_token    = var.do_token
  image        = "debian-11-x64"
  region       = "ams3"
  size         = "s-1vcpu-1gb"
  ssh_username = "root"
  monitoring = true
  snapshot_name = "packer-{{timestamp}}"
  droplet_name = "packer-build"
  ssh_key_id = id
  ssh_private_key_file = path/to/my/file
}
 
build {
  sources = ["source.digitalocean.example"]

  provisioner "file" {
    source = "publickeypath"
    destination = "/tmp/publickey.pub"
  }

  

  provisioner "ansible-local" {
    playbook_file = "../ansible/playbook.yml"
    extra_arguments= [ 
      "-vvv",
      "--extra-vars",
      "'ansible_python_interpreter=/usr/bin/python3'"
    ]
   
  }

}
```

I would like to provide an environment variable for my ssh private key instead of a file so i dont need to upload it to github...Is it possible?

Also for the public key, is it possible to provide an environment variable and copy it to a file (instead of build provisioner file)

Thank you

Comment: The build process should receive a private key dedicated for its own use, not share your private key. Keys are trivial to create (and replace if necessary).

Answer (score 0):

The answer is simple : make a runner and echo "$ENV_VARIABLE" > fileyouwant

```
- name: Make ssh private key from secret
  run: |
    echo "$PVT_KEY" > sshkey
  env:
    PVT_KEY: ${{ secrets.PVT_KEY }}
```